# MLTT not being Turing Complete

Tags: type-theory

Where can I find a proof that [Martin-Löf Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) isn't Turing Complete, if such proof exists?

Comment: Where have you looked? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried googling a lot

Comment: Well I also tried thinking about it being able to express Heyting arithmetic therefore also Peano by double  negation translation, therefore by Matiyasevich it is Turing complete. But i dont know if thats correct

Comment: That's too hand-wavy.  What does "express Heyting arithmetic" mean?

Comment: if it can express multivariate polynomials over the integers and equality of integers then it can express Hilbert 10th problem and then by Matiyasevich it is Turing complete. still handwavy and im still unsure though

Comment: @TroyMcClure Part of your confusion comes from the fact that you mistakenly think
Hilbert's 10th problem can be "represented" in MLTT. This is not the
case.  Let's recall that a solution to Hilbert's 10th problem is a
program that takes as input a (certain kind of) Diophantine equation
$D$ and returns (in a finite number of computable steps) true / false,
indicating whether $D$ has a (certain kind of) solution. No such
algorithm can be expressed in MLTT. It might be instructive for you to
try and write such an algorithm. (Continued below.)

Comment: (Continued from above.)
It is trivial to write such  a program in a general purpose language by suitable
diagonalisation over $\mathbb{Z}$ to search for solutions, but you won't
be able to write this diagonalisation in MLTT since you won't be able
to convince the type checker that the diagonalisation terminates
(because it doesn't in general).

Comment: convince type checker or termination checker? thats my confusion

Comment: @TroyMcClure Type- and termination check are the same thing in MLTT. Typing prevents you from writing non-terminating programs.

Comment: then why idris and agda apparently have those distinct?

Comment: @TroyMcClure It's convenient to separate recursion and proving well-foundedness of the recursion separately. Even a program like $gcd$ is annoying to write using just primitive recursion. Using general recursion and then proving that the recursion is well-founded is easer. Division of labour. However, under the hood, all the termination checker does is proving that the program could be reduced to primitive recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a general feature of reasonable total programming languages that they do not have self-interpreters, but interpreters for reasonable programming languages are Turing-computable. So, a concrete example of a total computable function which is not definable in a total programming language is an interpreter for that programming language.

See Definition 2.1, Theorem 2.2, and Corollary 2.3 of [this note](http://math.andrej.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/self-interpreter-for-T.pdf). It proves that a self-interpreter for Gödel's T is not definable in Gödel's T. You can use the exact same proof for MLTT.

It is generally well known that a confluent terminating normalization system such as that of MLTT leads to a Turing-computable normalization procedure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44678/discussion-on-answer-by-andrej-bauer-mltt-not-being-turing-complete).

Answer (score 0):

Section 4 of P. Martin-Löf's [An Intuitionistic Theory of Types](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/MartinL%C3%B6f1972.pdf) presents a normalisation proof of (a variant of) MLTT.

More (related) proofs can be found in the following papers.

- A. Abel, K. Aehlig, and P. Dybjer. [Normalization by evaluation for MartinLöf type theory with one universe](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/NbeMLTT.pdf).
- A. Abel, T. Coquand, and P. Dybjer. [Normalization by evaluation for MartinLöf Type Theory with typed equality judgements](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/NbeMLTTEqualityJudgements.pdf).

A problem with normalisation of MLTT is that there are many variants of MLTT, and even small changes in the definition of what MLTT is might have substantial effect on normalisation.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? If the former, I'd convert to a comment; if the latter, please expand a little bit to include more than just a link, which may break at any time.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. MLTT could be normalizing and still able to express all computations.

Comment: @Gilles in what sense?

Comment: @Gilles I wonder how? Doesn't the fact that every program terminates implies that a programming language is not Turing complete? How could a type theory be normalizing and express programs such as $\Omega$?